# Recursive parent child relationship in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following schema

```
  -- Menus
  create table public.menus (
    id uuid primary key default uuid_generate_v4(),
    name varchar(255) not null,
    description text null,
    group_type varchar(125) not null,
    status varchar(125) not null,
    type varchar(125) not null,
    level int not null,
    price int,
    category boolean default false,
    label varchar(125) not null,
    venue_id varchar(12) not null,
    variant_id uuid,
    created_at timestamptz not null,
    updated_at timestamptz not null default now()
  );

  -- Child/parent relationship table
  create table public.menus_menus (
    id uuid primary key default uuid_generate_v4(),
    parent_id uuid not null,
    child_id uuid not null,
    created_at timestamptz not null,
    updated_at timestamptz not null default now(),
    constraint fk_parent
      foreign key(parent_id)
        references public.menus(id),
    constraint fk_child
      foreign key(child_id)
        references public.menus(id)
  );
```

And some test data/rows

```
insert into public.menus
    (name, description, group_type, status, type, level, category, label, venue_id, created_at)
values
    ('test menu', 'test description', 'bar', 'live', 'bar', 0, false, 'A label', 'abc123', now());

insert into public.menus
    (name, description, group_type, status, type, level, category, label, venue_id, created_at)
values
    ('test category', 'test description', 'bar', 'live', 'bar', 1, true, 'A label', 'abc123', now());

-- Insert parent child relationship
insert into public.menus_menus
    (parent_id, child_id, created_at)
values
    ('83862417-ecd7-42fb-a381-1610929c59a5', '4510e71d-4585-4177-a110-8c4a31563ddc', now());
```

I'm attempting to build up a sort of nested relationship, which can be several levels deep. The structure I think works so far, I just can't figure out how to query the relationship table, in order to fetch the menus in a nested format.

I found the following example, which I tried to replicate and modify slightly to my needs, but I'm not really getting the expected results:

```
-- Recursively select parent/child structure
with recursive m as (
    select
        c.id
    from
        public.menus c
    left join
        public.menus_menus p on c.id = p.child_id
    union
    select
        me.child_id
    from
        public.menus_menus me
    inner join
        public.menus_menus on me.parent_id = public.menus_menus.child_id
)
select * from m;
```

The output I'm hoping for is something like:

```
id   | name | description | etc | level
abc  | Menu | Testing 123 | ... | 0
def  | Cat  | Testing 123 | ... | 1
```

So if I fetch a top level item by ID, it will return all of the children as rows, differentiated by, and ordered by the level column.

I'm unsure about the union I guess, although it's conceivable that this approach is entirely wrong as well. Is my approach sound or am I way off the mark?

Comment: What happens when you run the query?

Comment: Please show us the result that you want, as tabular text.

Comment: It returns a single row, child and root as ID's. Child seems to be the parent id and root seems to be the child ID. I'll add this to the post

Comment: @GMB I just updated the description with an example as to the kind of output I'mt trying to get to

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by getting rid of the join table and created a self-referential foreign key. Then updated my query to:

```
with recursive m as (
    select
        a.id,
        a.parent_id,
        a.name,
        a.level
    from
        public.menus a
    union
        select
            e.id,
            e.parent_id,
            e.name,
            e.level
        from
            public.menus e
        inner join m s on s.id = e.parent_id
)
select * from m;
```